# Any tips on how to fix this chipped bathroom countertop?

Tags: bathroom, countertops

Accidentally chopped off the corner of my bathroom counter top. Any tips on how to fix it? [image]

Comment: If you have all the pieces and don't mind a non perfect fix, a couple dabs of clear silicon should do it.  It will stick the pieces down and provide a water tight seal.

Comment: My tip would be to not even make an attempt. But we charge so much for our apartments that it doesn't matter. Lose the chips, and have artisan level expertise with white epoxy. GL.

Comment: If you try and fail, you aren't that much further behind... white two part epoxy is your friend.

Comment: @crip659 I think I might be more tempted to try epoxy.  Might even be able to get it in white, and use some wetsanding technique to get a nice smooth finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the fragments cyanoacrylate ("super glue") then touch up with appliance paint if needed (assuming you can get the right colour - you may want to take a chip to get matched first.)

If there's bits missing it's going to be a real mission to fill that with tinted epoxy.